# How I can create a Button that when I click, the Web Browser is Running

Tags: c#

I want to create a button, example: [Go]. when I click it, my Program will start web browser and browser a website.
Example: I click Google, the below web browser will display Google.com. 
when not click, the web browser not run.
I'm working with Visual Studio 2010, Winform C# Application.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Do you have code to share for what you have tried so far?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: hello, I will share with you later.

Comment: look at using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx]

Answer (score 1):

This is as simple as invoking a process

```
Process.Start("chrome.exe", "http:\\www.example.com");
```

above example is for google chrome, you may try with other browsers too.

Comment: thanks you, but i want to use a supported Web Browser in Visual Studio. I see it in Toolbox.

Comment: are you creating the button in Visual Studio toolbar, or are you creating a Visual Studio addon?

Comment: `Process.Start("http://www.example.com/");` is enough. This will launch it in the default browser.

Comment: You check my screen shot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzsNsI1N05QSbUVBM05GUnk2Uzg/view?usp=sharing
You will understand my question, cause I want to display web page on the windows of my program

Comment: I am sure What OP is looking for but It is truly a gentle answer.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from your question is you want to create a button where you click it would go to the address written in the address bar whereas if the address bar is blank WebBrowser would go Blank.

If this is the case ... this code might help you..

```
private void GotoAddress_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ///Check if the URL or Address bar is blank
    if(TxtWebAdd.Text != "")
    {
        Uri uriResult;
        ///if not then checking if the URL is valid 
        if(Uri.TryCreate(TxtWebAdd.Text, UriKind.Absolute, out uriResult) && uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp)
            wb1.Navigate(TxtWebAdd.Text);
        else
            MessageBox.Show("This is not a valid URL please check");
    }
    else
    {
        ///this is how it will navigate to blank page when WebAddress TextBox is blank.
        wb1.Navigate("about:blank");
    }
}
```